# Android HorizontalLitview refresh is not working

Tags: android, refresh, selecteditem, horizontallist

In my adapter class i have return a refresh custom method

```
public void refreshList(ArrayList<VehicleVo> list) {
    LogUtil.d("in Adaper class" + list.size());

    sRoutlist.clear();
    sRoutlist.addAll(list);

    LogUtil.d("sRoutlist" + sRoutlist.size());

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In this method my sRoutlist always return null, but `LogUtil.d("in Adaper class" + list.size());` in this log i can see actual size of my arraylist. dont know what mistake i have done. even its very silly question not able to find the proper solution kindly correct me

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten to initialize sRoutList (since it is null), try adding `sRoutList = new ArrayList();` somewhere before invocation of the refreshList

Comment: this is my adapter class so i have initialized sRoutlist in constructor itself

Comment: Can you please post your adapter class? If you initialize sRouthList in the constructor then it can't be null...

Comment: please post full code of adapter class